# What to do for reusing backing images for Ubuntu guests?

Tags: virtualization, configuration, virt-manager

I am currently using virt-manager on Ubuntu desktop to make VMs to test things and so I want to use backing images to quickly bring up a system whether it's a desktop or server install. Afterwards, I obviously have to make some changes to the new image in order to change hostname and things like that. But what exactly do I need to change on Ubuntu guests >=20.04?

I specifically want to do it by hand, so I want to know which files to change and how to do it, not how to use automation tools.

Comment: Can you use DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) on your "Ubuntu Desktop" to handle "change hostname and things like that"?

Comment: No. One of the problems is that your router will see your new system as the old one and assign the same IPs to all systems based on the same image. That's ok if you're just using one machine at a time, but once you're making several derivatives of the same image, you get IP conflicts. So there's going to be things that need change, but these days, we're told to use these advanced systems for configuring VMs automatically and there's really not a lot of documentation on what has to be changed.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad first a warning, of the many times I've seen people trying to "undo an image" and make a gold-image of it they mostly failed - instead I recommend to use a Ubuntu cloud-image and cloud-init to customize each system on first boot. But since you asked - the reason your DHCP server sees it as "the same" is most likely /etc/machine-id which you can remove (will be re-generated on boot) - please at least also make sure any host&ssh keys are removed.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt: I like to know how to do things manually before I start automating the things I do. Besides, using cloud-init is not documented either, so you're really just asking me to add another layer of undocumented complexity in order to learn the basics of Ubuntu. This is not how we're supposed to behave. Remember the whole traveler in the village thing? I know that I can download an Ubuntu image and read the source code, but that's how what I expect to be told in the Ubuntu community.

Comment: I told you what you need to remove to get the dhcp issue resolved (which I hoped helps you). And then I recommended something that you are free to ignore - btw cloud init isn't undocumented at all => https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt: The question is about how to learn. For instance, you seem to understand why I only have to change /etc/machine-id and not /var/lib/dbus/machine-id, but I don't know how to learn that.

Comment: Hi Jo, there is no single entity coordinating "what makes a system unique". Therefore there is no single place to learn about it. The ID above is from systemd, but there are other things you want to keep unique. It is an ongoing battle trying to keep on top of what is needed to be unique - and therefore (most of the time) it is better to not try to make an existing system "fresh" again. The best start for you to learn that I can recommend is to look at `virt-clone` which is a tool that tries to do that - look at it's code and development what it does which will give you a general overview.

Comment: This used to be so very simple. I hate having to use systems for basic stuff.